# context switching in an operating system

Tags: cpu

good evening everyone
I would like to know what will happen if during a context switch, the new context is already in one of the registers or if it is ever in memory and all the registers are occupied?

Comment: You need to provide more information. Please read [How do i ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: a computer with multiple sets of registers .. A0=(R1,......Rn).. An=(R11,...,Rnn).  I would like to know what are the actions that occur during a context switch if the new context is already in one of the sets of registers and what will happen if the new context is in memory and all the components of all registers are occupied

Answer (score 0):

Basically, a context switch is a way of saving the current state of the machine and replacing it with a new one. Steps are vaguely like this:

- enter privileged mode, where the CPU will have access to system/kernel memory
- save old program counter (now we know where we were when the task-switch event happened - maybe a system call, maybe an interrupt; basically the running process was forced to yield control)
- save current register state (either on the stack, or in a specific set of OS-allocated-and-managed memory)
- save the stack pointer (if the architecture has one)
- save memory information for the task being suspended by marking all the pages used by this process as eligible for eviction (if the next task or the OS needs the main memory that the old process was using, that will be copied out to page storage and then memory-mapped into the correct address space; if not, they may hang around and be available when the task regains control)

It is now safe for the OS to do anything it pleases, as the transient state of the old process is saved, and its memory is safe. Maybe it handles an interrupt, or executes a system call. We'll skip all that and just do a task switch.

- set up memory for new task (map main memory to the new process's virtual memory; some may be in main memory already, if there's not a lot of memory in use, or it may have been paged out to external storage, in which case it will be loaded via a "page fault" when the program tries to reference it - the program will suspend in the same way as above, the OS will read in the memory block, and the process will be resumed by the OS)
- load register state from the new process's OS control block or stack
- load the stack pointer if required
- exit privileged mode
- branch to the last suspend program counter or entry point for new task

The key point is that the the OS is in charge of preserving state; it manages this process appropriately for the CPU architecture. Registers are not "busy" because the task switch process saves them and restores them. The process which lost control then regained it does not have any idea that it lost control; its world state is saved and restored seamlessly.